# QTableView in a popup on a QPushButton click

Tags: c++, qt

Click the button, a table control appears next to the button, click the blank space or the content in the control to close.

I have two ideas:

1. With the **popmenu**, can ***click the blank space or the content in the control to close the control***, but it does not meet my needs for a table-type control
2. New a **tableview**, but I don’t know how to accurately appear under the button and realize the function of ***clicking the blank space or the content in the control to close the control***

**Update：**

I need to use Qt to implement a function, but I don't know how to implement it.

The functions are as follows:

Click a **QPushButton**, and a **QTableView** is displayed below the button. I can click anywhere outside the **QTableView** to close this **QTableView**

There are two things I cannot achieve:

1.How to display the **QTableView** below the **QPushButton** (must be immediately below, such as:
[image: Sketch]
<sub>(source: [upload.cc](https://upload.cc/i1/2020/12/07/YZnL4b.png))</sub>

)

2.How to close the **QTableView** by clicking the blank space outside the **QTableView**

Comment: We are going to need a lot more context to be able to answer your question. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and come back to improve your question to make it more appealing. As it stands I don't think anybody can understand what you want to do.

Comment: _Click a QPushButton, and a QTableView is displayed below the button. I can click anywhere outside the QTableView to close this QTableView_ This strongly reminds me to a [QComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html). Please, note this: _You can also set a new model and view (with setModel() and setView())._ i.e. you may override the popup's contents with `QTableView` and the appropriate model to your needs and probably get the rest of your requirement "for free".

Comment: Realize this function by customizing QComboBox! Thanks, you solved my problem @Scheff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make all of this in the same **window**, it's simple...

To position the `QTableView` below the `QPushButton` you will use `Qt Designer`, and setup the `QTableView` to `hide();`. And when the `QPushButton` is clicked, he setup the `QTableView` to `show();`.

An `show();` example:

```cpp
QTableView *nametable = ui->tableView;
nametable->show(); //will appears
```

But to close or `hide();` this when clicked in a blank space I don't know how to help you...

Comment: This is indeed a novel idea; but if the `QTableView` cannot `close()` or `hide()` by click in the blank space, it may cause some interaction problems. I have another idea: use `Qt designer` to create a `Dialog`, use `setWindowFlags(windowFlags()|Qt::FramelessWindowHint)` to remove the border, and put a `QTableView` in the `Dialog`. The problem with this idea is how to accurately display the `Dialog` below the `QPushButton`